# Wordpress Theme alignment issue

Tags: css, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I have some trouble with a WP Theme.. On this URL: [Website](http://restaureringsprosjekt.no/)
If you se the "Vi tilbyr" and the "Kontakt" the boxes that contain these words seems to be out of alignment. And kind of weird looking.. Especially the "Kontakt" so out of alignment compared to the form under it.

Tell me if you need any code!
Sorry for bad description, I'm kind of new here..

Answer (score 0):

You've given the `.section-title` a static height, resulting in the word not standing in the vertical middle of the box.

If you want the `.section-title`s in the middle, you should change the margin-left to 50% of that div's width. Since you don't give them any completely unique classes (both "kontakt" and "vi tilbyr" have the same class), you can't give it the same margin-left.

In case of "vi tilbyr", you should have a margin-left of `-107px`, with "kontakt" you need `-93px`

So start with giving them a unique class as well, and target that one and add the correct margin-left.